# Process affinity goes to {0} after large array multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, openmp

System Info:

- OS: CentOS Linux 7
- Processors: 24x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6140 CPU @ 2.30GHz

Software Info:

- Python 3.7.3
- NumPy 1.16.2

I tracked this down as a result of trying to fit a [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) on a 1M record dataset in parallel (`n_jobs=-1`). Upon fitting I noticed the `joblib` backend had reverted to the `SequentialBackend` running 1 job at a time.

I established that upon calling `fit` the process affinity (as shown by `os.sched_getaffinity`) had been set to a single core instead of the normal 24. It turns out that in the data transformations there is a step in which a `numpy.array` is multiplied by a `float`. At this point there is a cascade of messages thrown by OpenMP regarding KMP_AFFINITY, none of which seem to indicate the process has been set to a single core, but I am not an expert in OpenMP logging. Below is a simple example that reproduces this error on my system.

```
import numpy as np
from os import sched_getaffinity as aff

aff(0)
{0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23}
arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
arr *= .5
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-23
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 24 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 24 packages x 1 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (24 total cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 2
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 4
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 6
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 4 maps to package 8
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 5 maps to package 10
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 6 maps to package 12
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 7 maps to package 14
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 8 maps to package 16
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 9 maps to package 18
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 10 maps to package 20
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 11 maps to package 22
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 12 maps to package 24
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 13 maps to package 26
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 14 maps to package 28
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 15 maps to package 30
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 16 maps to package 32
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 17 maps to package 34
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 18 maps to package 36
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 19 maps to package 38
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 20 maps to package 40
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 21 maps to package 42
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 22 maps to package 44
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 23 maps to package 46
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 8822 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9374 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9375 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9376 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9377 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9378 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 5
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9380 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 7
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9379 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9381 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 8
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9383 thread 10 bound to OS proc set 10
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9382 thread 9 bound to OS proc set 9
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9384 thread 11 bound to OS proc set 11
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9385 thread 12 bound to OS proc set 12
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9386 thread 13 bound to OS proc set 13
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9387 thread 14 bound to OS proc set 14
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9388 thread 15 bound to OS proc set 15
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9389 thread 16 bound to OS proc set 16
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9390 thread 17 bound to OS proc set 17
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9391 thread 18 bound to OS proc set 18
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9392 thread 19 bound to OS proc set 19
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9394 thread 21 bound to OS proc set 21
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9393 thread 20 bound to OS proc set 20
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9395 thread 22 bound to OS proc set 22
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 8822 tid 9396 thread 23 bound to OS proc set 23

aff(0)
{0}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to explain this behavior, and even resetting the process affinity with `os.sched_setaffinity` afterwards does not restore the capacity to use all cores.

#### N.B.

This does not occur when the size of the array is 1e5 instead of 1e6. Memory is not an issue as this system has 256GB.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket on the OpenMP bugzilla page under [Multiplication of array with float causes cascade of OpenMP messages and sets process affinity to {0}](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43303).

The suggestion I got from one of the Intel engineers was to use the `norespect` `KMP_AFFINITY` modifier. Documentation for this and other modifiers can be found in [Intel C++ Compiler Developer Guide - Thread Affinity Interface](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-thread-affinity-interface-linux-and-windows#KMP_AFFINITY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE). This worked for me.

```
export KMP_AFFINITY=norespect

ipython
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from os import sched_getaffinity as aff
In [3]: aff(0)
Out[3]:
{0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23}
In [4]: arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
In [5]: arr *= .5
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #155: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set not respected: 0-23
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 24 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 24 packages x 1 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (24 total cores)
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4274 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4697 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4698 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4699 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4700 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4701 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4702 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4703 thread 9 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4704 thread 10 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4705 thread 11 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4706 thread 12 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4708 thread 14 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4709 thread 15 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4710 thread 16 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4711 thread 17 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4712 thread 18 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4714 thread 20 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4715 thread 21 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4716 thread 22 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4717 thread 23 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4713 thread 19 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4707 thread 13 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4695 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 0-23
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 4274 tid 4696 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 0-23
In [6]: aff(0)
Out[6]:
{0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23}
```